# request.getParamater encoding utf-8

Tags: java, string

I want to get my parameters from the request (characters with accents) but it doesn't work.

I tried to user request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") but it didn't work either.
how can i solve this problem?
thanks.

Comment: [We need proper info](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/77-doesntwork)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `ServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding` says the following.

> ... This method must be called prior to reading request parameters or reading input using getReader(). Otherwise, it has no effect.

[ServletRequest (JavaEE 7 JavaDoc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding-java.lang.String-)

If that doesn't help, you can convert your `byte` array to a new `String` object, and supply the charset.

```java
try (InputStream stream = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream())) {
    byte[] bytes = stream.readAllBytes();
    String string = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Additionally, you can try using the following, as opposed to explicitly typing "UTF-8".

```java
request.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```